# Taking address of RVO-optimized static

Tags: c++, singleton, static-variables, return-value-optimization

In the following code I try to register a singleton instance with a global array that keeps all singletons (in production code I can instantiate different singletons based on template parameters so don't worry about this paradox :) ). What I wanted to know is if I can somehow get the address of to-be return type of the lambda which is ought to be return value optimized anyway, so I can register it with the global entries array.

Here's what I've got:

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:32,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:32,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27%23include+%3Cranges%3E%0A%23include+%3Ccstdio%3E%0A%23include+%3Ccstdint%3E%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0Anamespace+rng+%3D+std::ranges%3B%0A%0Astruct+MyStruct+%7B%0A++++uint32_t+a+%3D+0%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Astruct+AllStructs+%7B%0A++++std::array%3CMyStruct*,+10%3E+items+%3D+%7B+0+%7D%3B%0A++++std::size_t+count+%3D+0%3B%0A%7D+g_entries%3B%0A%0Aauto+get_instance()+%7B%0A++++static+MyStruct+instance+%3D+%5B%5D()+-%3E+MyStruct%7B%0A++++++++MyStruct+ret%7B+15+%7D%3B%0A++++++++g_entries.items%5Bg_entries.count%2B%2B%5D+%3D+%26ret%3B%0A++++++++return+ret%3B%0A++++%7D()%3B%0A%0A++++return+instance%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++auto+instance+%3D+get_instance()%3B%0A%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+%22my+a+%3D+%22+%3C%3C+instance.a+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:45.62575941676793,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang_trunk,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Os+-Wall+-pthread%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+clang+(trunk)+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+clang+(trunk)+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:54.37424058323208,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```
#include <ranges>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

namespace rng = std::ranges;

struct MyStruct {
    uint32_t a = 0;
};

struct AllStructs {
    std::array<MyStruct*, 10> items = { 0 };
    std::size_t count = 0;
} g_entries;

auto get_instance() {
    static MyStruct instance = []() -> MyStruct{
        MyStruct ret{ 15 };
        g_entries.items[g_entries.count++] = &ret;
        return ret;
    }();

    return instance;
}

int main() {
    [[maybe_unused]] auto instance = get_instance();

    std::cout << "my a = " << instance.a << std::endl;
    std::cout << "my a from array = " << g_entries.items[0]->a << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
my a = 15
my a from array = 0
```

It doesn't work like this at least, as the entry gleaned from the array is still 0. How can I work around this?

**Further notes**:

- I can't use dynamic memory allocation in this code section!

Comment: there is no rvo for static, how can it be static if it's created in local scope?

Comment: Remark : `auto get_instance()`  I hope you mean `auto& get_instance()` or do you still want copies?

Comment: @PepijnKramer Oops!

Comment: It happens :) `[[maybe_unused]] auto instance = get_instance();` should also be `[[maybe_unused]] auto& instance = get_instance();`  (deleting copy constructors from MyStruct  would show these errors too)

Comment: @appleappk Does that actually matter? I think of RVO as "construct return object at address given by the caller from the start". In this case that address would be the static. Correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NRVO is not mandatory. But you can just take the address of the result object directly:

```cpp
auto& get_instance() {
    static MyStruct instance = []() -> MyStruct {
        MyStruct ret{ 15 };
        g_entries.items[g_entries.count++] = &instance;
        return ret;
    }();

    // Or if you don't otherwise need `ret`
    static MyStruct instance = []{
        g_entries.items[g_entries.count++] = &instance;
        return MyStruct{ 15 };
    }();

    return instance;
}
```

Comment: Ohh amazing, i didn't know you could do that! And I don't even need to capture it...

Comment: I just saw that RVO is not performed which is bad in my case because in my case MyStruct is a huge array that gets allocated on stack and causes a stack overflow. is there a way to directly construct to the static?